# saddle valve cap not fitting

Tags: plumbing

Seen a lot of answers about bad saddle valves, and I was just going to use a threaded cap. I bought this cap - Anderson Metals 56108 Brass Pipe Fitting, Cap, 1/4" NPT Female Pipe. Had the teflon tape an was ready to go but when I tried the cap it was to big? Why did it not fit? Is this cap different than a 1/4 inch threaded compression cap? Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That saddle valve discharge is not 1/4" pipe thread but instead is a 1/4" OD compression fitting. If you want to cap that fitting you need to purchase a cap for the 1/4" OD compression fitting. One thing to remember, not only can the valve leak but the rubber washer that seals the saddle to copper tubing will harden with time and could also fail. I hated saddle valves as a cheap install and instead used a "fitting by 1/4" pipe bushing" to make the connection or solder in a ball valve in standard copper and reduce it's discharge to 1/4" OD copper. my 2 cents